# How to distribute DIVS evenly (horizontal and vertical) that floats with each other?

Tags: html, css

So here's my current dilemma, what I'm trying to achieve here is something like this:

[image]

Just please ignore all the contents of each boxes/divs. notice that the 6 boxes floats with each other perfectly and evenly. That's what I'm trying to replicate.

So I have my own codes:

**HTML**

```
<div class="tentofifteen">
    <section class="grid-superloop-ten" id="wired-superloop">
    </section>
    
    <section class="grid-superloop-eleven" id="wired-superloop">
    </section>
    
    <section class="grid-superloop-twelve" id="wired-superloop">
    </section>

    <section class="grid-superloop-thirteen" id="wired-superloop">
    </section>

    <section class="grid-superloop-fourteen" id="wired-superloop">
    </section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    <style>


.tentofifteen {
    height: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}
#wired-superloop {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
.tentofifteen:after {
    content:"";
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}

.grid-superloop-ten {width:319px; min-height:700px;background:#CCC;}
.grid-superloop-eleven {width:220px; min-height:350px; background:#009;}
.grid-superloop-twelve {width:437px; min-height:350px; background:#F36;}
.grid-superloop-thirteen {width:337px; min-height:350px; background:#CC9;}
.grid-superloop-fourteen {width:319px; min-height:350px; background:#0F0;}
    
    
    
    
    
        </style>
```

Now, the result of this is not really successful. Which I have no idea how to figure out to float the last two divs.

here's the screen shot.

[image]

Any ideas what's wrong with the code? Could you please help to solve the issue?

Comment: Use flexbox, not floats.

Comment: Lots of ppl broke their back over getting this done. You are essentially looking for a 'masonry grid'. The JS library 'masonry' is one example. For a pure CSS version I suggest having a look at this: [Three Super Easy Ways to Pull Off a Masonry Layout](http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/). The third solution is pure CSS.

You will learn that it is rather hard to get it done and need to use **@media queries**.

Google for 'like masonry without JS' and you will get a multitude of examples to select from...

Comment: Yeah I agree. I decided to use the Masonry instead of pure css. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try masonry https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/66/

**JS**

```
$('.tentofifteen').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 1
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tentofifteen">
    <section class="grid-superloop-ten grid-item" id="wired-superloop">
    </section>

    <section class="grid-superloop-eleven grid-item" id="wired-superloop">
    </section>

    <section class="grid-superloop-twelve grid-item" id="wired-superloop">
    </section>

    <section class="grid-superloop-thirteen grid-item" id="wired-superloop">
    </section>

    <section class="grid-superloop-fourteen grid-item" id="wired-superloop">
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Nenad! Thanks for your answer. I have considered using it but was wondering if this can be done purely in CSS?

Comment: I guess as Madara Uchiha said using flexbox but i don't have much experience with it so i can't suggest it. But since your elements width is fixed i think masonry is best solution but i might be wrong here.

Comment: Dude. thanks for your help! I decided to use masonry just to get over this. :)

Comment: Glad i could help. Also after i posted this answer i tried to do the same thing with flexbox but i couldn't figure it out.